# Is ostracism a common practice of the administators of this website?

Tags: discussion

I was bold enough, in a post of mine on English Language and Usage, to contend that language is political, whether we like it or not, and I feel that since then, my account has been 'frozen' in some way, intentionally ignored... Am I right or is it just an impression I am under?

Comment: Site moderators aren't able to "shadow ban" or force people to ignore your posts. If people aren't voting on your posts, it is likely an issue with the posts visibility because the question isn't very interesting, lack of supporting references, or something similar.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to indicate what the effects of this "freezing" are, but I can say that *any* action taken against you by moderators or staff is entirely transparent to you (although deliberately not so to others). If you haven't been told of anything, then it ain't happening.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Given your diamond hat, you could be a little more definitive and specific in this case, and outright tell OP he hasn’t had any kid sanctions (or, if he has, send him a follow-up mod message). You needn’t say “if mods did such and such, then so and so”... you can just say whether or not miss actually did such and such.

Comment: @DanBron He’s probably restricted by agreement not to publicise private matters such as mod actions. By extension, he might be restricted from announcing the lack of mod actions as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the sake of an answer here, I’ll repackage and expand on the comments of ColleenV and Andrew Leach.

If it helps for credibility, I represent a “trusted user” (ie, with >25k rep points) and thus have [all the powers SE can grant to non-mod users](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), and Andrew Leach is actually a mod here, who has [all the powers SE grants to non-employees](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators). Similarly, ColleenV is actually [a mod on our sister site, ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators&filter=month).

First, [to echo Andrew](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11915/is-ostracism-a-common-practice-of-the-administators-of-this-website#comment51144_11915): we could help you better if you were a little more specific and concrete on exactly what symptoms you’re feeling which you have described as “ostracization”.

But, [following Colleen’s logic](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11915/is-ostracism-a-common-practice-of-the-administators-of-this-website#comment51143_11915) and inferring by ostracizing you simply mean that your posts don’t seem to be attracting the kind of attention (in terms of votes or comments or both) that you expect or have experienced on previous posts, that’s not a power anyone here has: not low rep users, nor high rep users, [nor even elected diamond moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75189/273503)¹.

In theory, I suppose it’s possible that SE the company has some “[shadowban](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_banning)” mechanism, but if they do, I’ve never heard it mentioned before, and I read the Meta sites pretty regularly, so if it existed, I’d expect to have seen *someone* complain about it, even if the company itself doesn’t want to publicize its existence².

Even if they do have it, I think it very unlikely they’d apply it for political reasons. SE as a company would only really care if there were commercial or PR impacts, and I doubt some post about language being political creates that kind of risk for them. Plus, historically, they’ve handled PR snafus through the normal mechanisms of deleting, redacting (only in extreme cases), and shutting down accounts.

So absent some grand conspiracy at work... no, no one is deliberately ostracizing you. As you spend time here, you’ll note that the [posts you spend a lot of time and expertise composing](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/331618/55623) get relatively few views, and [popular responses to simple questions you fire off in minutes](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/255969/55623) get a flood.

C’est le vie. Welcome to EL&U.

---

¹ <sub>In particular, the publicly [enumerated powers of the various classes of SE employee](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158215/273503) that rank above “elected moderator” (like Community Managers) don’t  include shadowbanning, meaning it’s likely that only SE developers with database access or the executives that can direct them have the power to shape the site in the way that worries you.</sub>

² <sub>Unless the shadowban worked really, really well, of course...</sub>